# How can I get facebook access tokem from Azure mobile service client SDK

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-mobile-services

I believe that auth token that we have in user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken is the access token for the azure mobile service, my app needs to upload the image to user's FB album, so I need Facebook auth token on the client side, so that client can upload the pictures directly, it doesn't make sense to first send the pictures to backend and backend uploads the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I known, you could retrieve the tokens from the client by sending an authenticated GET request to `/.auth/me` endpoint, then you would get a JSON response that contains a richer set of information about the logged in user as follows:

https://brucechen-mobile.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me

[image]

For refreshing tokens, you could call the built-in endpoint `/.auth/refresh`. For more details, you could follow this [tutorial](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) for a better understanding of Azure App Service Token Store.

Comment: I am using Azure mobile service client to make the api call, can I use InvokeAPISync(). not sure whether .auth is api name and me is parameter or not. Or just make a raw http request to .auth/me

Comment: Yes, you are right. After you have logon successfully by calling `LoginAsync`, you could try to call `MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/ne")` to retrieve your logged info.

Comment: @Anu If it helps you, please try to mark it as an answer.

Comment: I am not able to mark it as answer, stack overflow is not allowing me to either vote or marking the answer

Comment: Here is a [issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about how to mark an answer as accepted, you could refer to it.

Comment: Any concerns, please feel free to let us know.